# Is every countable discrete group a subgroup of a non discrete Lie group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

1)Let  $G$ be  a  countable  discrete group. Can $G$ be embbeded in a  locally connected Lie group?

2)let $G$ be a countable discrete group with a prescribed generating set and corresponding word metric. Can $G$ be embbeded isometrically in a locally connected Lie group with its left invariant  metric?

**Remark**: We emphasis on the word  "**Locally** connected" because of the example $G\subset \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0 \}$ with $G=\{\pm e^n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with multiplication.

Comment: I assume you want more conditions, or else you can just take $G \times \mathbb R$?

Comment: @KevinCasto  Thank you for your attention. To be honnest I was considering $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \subset S^1$. Could you please help me to impose some extra conditions to have a minimal number of connect compenent. I had intention to ask "A connected Lie group". I am not sure if there is  a  connected Lie group containing the example in the "Remark".

Comment: @KevinCasto  Infact one feel that $\mathbb{R}$ intrincically contains $\mathbb{Z}$. The same for$S^1$ containing finite cyclic group. So accoring to your interesting comment one impose the following question: Let G be a countable discrete group. Is $G$ a subgroup of a connected Lie group?

Comment: In that case there is a huge literature on this subject. See e.g. this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110208/understanding-groups-that-are-not-linear I suppose technically you need to worry about nonlinear Lie groups like $\widetilde{SL_2}(\mathbb R)$ but I suspect the properties listed in the first answer to that question also apply to discrete subgroups of this.

Comment: @KevinCasto Thank you for this link. Befor I start reading this link, do you say that the link contains an answer to the question that every countable group is (isometrically) a subgroup  of  a  connected Lie group?

Comment: Every Lie group is locally connected, so the answer to your question is obviously yes since every countable discrete group is a Lie group. On the other hand, many countable discrete groups do not embed (even algebraically) in connected Lie groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohanThank you. By locally connected I was (somehow) meant : non discrete.May be some example for your last sentemse?this is what I search for.

Comment: If you mean nondiscrete, then the firs comment by Kevin answers the question. As for examples, take any centerless nonresidually finite group such as BS(2,3), Baumslag Solitar group. Or take any group with undecidable word problem if you want a more exotic example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  So I realize that the ocean  of Lie groups is wider and deeper  than I imagined. Among various example you and Kevin pointed ot, what is  a  precise example of a countable group not embaddable in a connected lie group of dimension at least 1.

Comment: @KevinCasto  Please read my previous comment.

Comment: $BS(2,3)=<a,b| ab^2a^{-1}=b^3>$ does not embed in a connected Lie group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Ok thanks,I try to understand the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Malcev proved that every finitely-generated matrix group $\Gamma$ (over any field) is [residually finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group), i.e. the intersection of all finite-index subgroups of $\Gamma$ is $\{1\}$. [Baumslag-Solitar groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group), such as $BS(2,3)= \langle a, b | ab^2 a^{-1} =b^3\rangle$, are among simplest examples of finitely generated groups which are not residually finite. A  connected Lie group $G$ need not be linear (the universal covering group of $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ is a standard example). However, the kernel of the adjoint representation $Ad_G$ of a connected Lie group $G$ is always contained in the center of $G$. Thus, if $\Gamma< G$ is a centerless subgroup, then the restriction of the adjoint representation $Ad_G$  to $\Gamma$ is faithful and, hence, $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to a matrix group. It is not hard to see that $BS(2,3)$ has trivial center. Thus, this group is not isomorphic to a subgroup of any connected Lie group. The same proof shows that $BS(2,3)$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of a Lie group with finitely many components.

Remark. The standard definition of "[locally connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space)" in topology is that every point should have a neighborhood basis consisting of connected subsets. Hence, each manifold (in particular, each Lie group) is, by definition, locally connected. Given your example, it seems that what you really had in mind is that a Lie group $G$ should have [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification) $G\cup \{\infty\}$, such that $\infty$ admits a neighbourhood basis $U_i$ satisfying the condition that $U_i\cap G$ is connected. It is easy to see that  this requirement is equivalent to the condition that $G$ is connected and 1-ended (equivalently, is neither compact nor a product of compact group with ${\mathbb R}$). I am not sure what to call this property, let's name it ($*$). Then every discrete countable group $\Gamma$ embeds in a Lie group with property ($*$), e.g., $G=\Gamma \times {\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: Hi Moishe. This isn't really appropriate for the MO comment format, but I would like to say I have learned a lot from you and your perspective over the years. Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Sure, you are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

I would have posted this as a comment, but I have not yet unlocked that privilege. For a simpler example than Moishe Kohan's, the group $\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed in any connected Lie group, since a torsion subgroup of a connected Lie group $G$ is contained in a maximal compact subgroup of $G$ (this is a [result](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-055-02/S0002-9939-1976-0393342-6/S0002-9939-1976-0393342-6.pdf) of D. H. Lee), and it is easy to see that $\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed in $\mathrm{U}(n)$ for any $n$. Also, it follows from the Tits alternative for linear groups that any group that is not virtually solvable and does not contain a nonabelian free subgroup does not embed in a connected Lie group (or a Lie group with finitely many connected components).