$p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group satisfies a pro-$p$ identity?
Let $p$ be a prime. Let $w$ be an element of a free pro-$p$ group $F_r$ of finite rank $r\geq 2$. Then we say that a pro-$p$ group $G$ satisfies the pro-$p$ identity
$w$ if for every homomorphism $ f:F_r\to G$ we have $f(w)=1$. So, is it known that any $p$-adic analytic pro-$p$ group $G$ satisfies some (nontrivial) pro-$p$ identity $w$? Any relevant literature would be appreciated.

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/243539/14094

I think they should! Barnea and Larsen proved that non-abelain free pro-$p$ groups are not linear over non-archimedian local fields, but $G$ being $p$-adic analytic is linear over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and hence over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. It follows that a presentation of $G$ as a quotient of $F_r$, for some $r$, has a non-trivial kernel.

@YassineGuerboussa We need to prove a stronger statement that the intersection of all such non-trivial kernels is also non-trivial.

@stupidboy, Yes you are right, I was not careful. Also, Barnea and Larsen's result is not needed above because $F_r$, being of infinte rank,  cannot embedded in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Nevertheless, the situation is not much different if we want to argue for the general case. All can be reduced to one universal group!

The question is closely related to that of the linearity (via continuous representations) of the free pro-$p$ group $F_r$ aver  pro-$p$ rings.  Using the universal property of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra $\Lambda_p$ of formal power series in $rn^2$ commuting variables $x_{ij}^{k}$, with $1\leq i,j\leq n$ and $1\leq k\leq r$,  the latter question can be reduced to examining just one pro-$p$ group, say $H_p(n)$.
Firstly, $\Lambda_p$ can be viewed as a pro-$p$ ring with the topology defined by the family of ideals $B_{l,m}$, where $B_{l,m}$ is formed by all the power series $f=\sum a_w w$, with $v_p(a_w)\geq l$ for $w$ of degree $\leq m-1$. Next we can consider the congruence subgroup $\Gamma\leq \mathrm{GL}_n(\Lambda_p)$ defined by the ideal of formal power series with zero constant terms; thus $\Gamma$ is a pro-$p$ group which contains the matrices $1+X_k$, $k=1,\ldots,r$, where $X_k=(x_{ij}^{k})$. We define $H_p(n)$ to be the closed subgroup generated by all the matrices $1+X_k$.  This group satisfies the following two interesting properties:

For any pro-$p$ ring $R$, and every family of square matrices $f_k=(f_{ij}^{(k)})$, $k=1,\ldots,r$, with  $f_{ij}^{(k)}$ lying in the Jacobson radical of $R$ (to ensure convergence), there exists a (continuous) group morphism from $H_p(n)$ onto the pro-$p$ group generated by the matrices $1+f_k$. This is readily seen since the map $x_{ij}^{(k)}\mapsto f_{ij}^{(k)}$ extends to a (continuous) $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra morphism from $\Lambda_p$ to $R$, which in turns extends to the corresponding matrix rings, and induces then the desired group morphism.

$H_p(n)$ is free iff $F_k$ embeds (continuously) in $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ for some pro-$p$ (or, more generally, profinite) ring $R$. The direct implication is obvious (take $R=\Lambda_p$); for the converse, one can reduce the problem to the case where $F_k$ lies in the congruence subgroup defined by the Jacobson radical of $R$, and then use (1) to see that $H_p(n)$ maps onto $F_r$, and so $H_p(n)\cong F_r$, as desired.


The result (2) is due to Zubkov (see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00969315).
Returning to your question, note that an analytic pro-$p$ group $G$ embeds in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for some $n$, and that $G$ satisfies a pro-$p$ identity iff the intersection $G_1$ of $G$ with the congruence subgroup $\mathrm{GL}_n^1(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ (defined by the ideal $p\mathbb{Z}_p$) does (this is obvious since $G/G_1$ is finite). So we may assume without loss of generality that $G\leq \mathrm{GL}_n^1(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. Thus all is reduced to checking pro-$p$-identities in $\mathrm{GL}_n^1(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. By virtue of (1), this would be the case if $H_p(n)$ does, i.e., $H_p(n)$ is not free (by virtue of (1), again).
Zubkov proved that this is the case for $n=2$ and $p>2$. Recently, the latter was completed to $p=2$ by Ben-Ezra and Zelmanov. According to Zelmanov, for $n$ fixed, $H_p(n)$ satisfies a pro-$p$ identity provided that $p$ is greater than some integer $g(n)$. The proof is sketched in the expository paper "Infinite Algebras and Pro-$p$ Groups", Progress in Mathematics, Vol. 248, 403–-413. As far as I'm aware, the full proof was never published. Further, still, one has to remove the restriction on $p$. Thus your question is still open in full generality.
